# Can't make gnuplot plot timestamps

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I'm trying to make gnuplot plot battery charging gathered by a program against timestamps. Here's my gnuplot script and the data I'm trying to plot below it.

```
   set term x11
   set xlabel "Time"
   set xdata time
   set timefmt "%H:%M:%S"
   set ylabel "Battery Percent"
   plot "charge5.dat" using 2:5 with points
```

And a sample of the data plot I'm using:

```
13:53:16 95
13:53:16 95
13:53:16 95
13:55:16 95
13:55:16 95
13:55:16 95
13:57:16 95
13:57:16 95
13:59:16 96
13:59:16 96
13:59:16 96
14:01:16 96
14:01:16 96
14:01:16 96
14:03:16 96
14:03:16 96
14:05:16 96
14:05:16 96
14:05:16 96
14:07:16 96
14:07:50 100
```

Everything I've found says that this should work, and I'm stumped. I would appreciate some help, I'm sure my problem is a simple one.
Thanks!

~

Answer (score 0):

As shown, your data has time in the first column and charge in the second column.
So the plot command would be

```
plot "charge5.dat" using 1:2 with points
```